# an adjective that describes a document that is issued in the very end of a year

Tags: word-request, adjectives

I need an adjective that describes a document that is issued in the very end of a year, namely an academic year in school or college.

Let's say it is a report card. What adjective would fit here the best?

1. year-end report card  ?
2. final yearly report card  ?
3. whole-year report card  ?
4. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A “year-end report card” sounds most natural. Note that “year” would refer to an academic year, which in some places does not match a calendar year.

“whole-year” means it covers an entire year, whereas “year-end” may only cover part of a year, such as if there was a “mid-year” report card that covered the first half.

“final” means it’d be the last one, regardless of when it happened. If you graduate or drop out, the report you had received last becomes your “final” one retroactively.

Answer (score 0):

I will personaly use the word **certificate**, something like

> End of the year certificate

[cambridge dictionary meaning](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/certificate)

Comment: Thanks, but I was requesting an adjective.